# Java time spinner showing date date fields

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to display a time only picker with hours and minutes in a dialog box with java. However, it renders with full date and time formatting.

My code is below:

```
 Date date = new Date();
 SpinnerDateModel sm = new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
 JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(sm);
 JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "HH:mm");

 int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, spinner, "Create a new alarm", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
 if (option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
     // user hit cancel
 } 
 else if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
    // user entered a time
 }
```

[image]

Comment: You've probably forgot to set the editor. Something like `spinner.setEditor(de);`

Answer (score 0):

I replaced it with this and it works:

```
SimpleDateFormat model = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel());
spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, model.toPattern()));
```